# Introduction to SharePoint Designer 2007 object model using VBA

Tags: html, sharepoint-2007

I'm finding it really difficult to find an introduction to the object model used within Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2007. For some reason, the online help if full of "Page not found". I suspect it's similar to the object model used in Internet Explorer DOM. The reference manual is in MSDN online (but not in my local copy) but as with many help systems like this, you have to know what you're doing pretty well before you can use a reference.

All I want to do at first is implement a darn macro to paste text into a web page without having to keep click Edit, Paste Text, OK :-)

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob - If you haven't found your answer yet - have you seen the SharePoint Designers Developer Reference in the MSDN Library? Some of the conceptual articles there might help you - such as this one on exploring procedures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208643.aspx

You might also try asking for help in teh SharePoint development discussion group: http://www.microsoft.com/office/community/en-us/default.mspx?dg=microsoft.public.sharepoint.development_and_programming&lang=en&cr=US

Best,
Stephanie

Answer (score 0):

Having just spent hours trying to find the answer, here's a link to help.  The above Microsoft links take you to a blank page - the object model reference is at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149156(v=office.12).aspx

It appears there are no other articles - anywhere - on the Internet specific to SharePoint Designer VBA coding.  Nor do there seem to be any books on the subject.

If you know VBA already, the link above should help you; otherwise, we seem to be pretty much on our own!

Andy

Comment: Thanks for the link. In the end I gave up and just got used to selecting paste text manually. Maybe I'll revisit